# Unity помощь в скрипте

Tags: c#, unity3d

Что я пишу не так?
По идее, этот скрипт должен двигать прицел по кругу, вокруг персонажа и следовать за указателем мыши, но прицел крутится только на одной половине экрана.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Crosshair : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject CrossHair;
//public float zDistance = 10f;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    MoveCrossHair();

}
private void MoveCrossHair(){
    var mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    Vector3 aim = new Vector3(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, mousePos.z);
    if (aim.magnitude > 0.0f){
        aim.Normalize();
        aim *= 2f;
        CrossHair.transform.position = aim;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input.mousePosition - возвращает вам положение курсора в экранных координатах, где левый нижний угол (0,0), а правый (ширина, высота) разрешения.

При этом, видимо, ваш персонаж стоит в мировых координатах (0,0) поэтому и получается, что прицел всегда справа от него. В вашем случае я бы предложил использовать вот такой код:

```
[SerializeField]
GameObject CrossHair;

[SerializeField]
float _distance;

void Update()
{
    Move();
}

void Move()
{
    var mousePos = Input.mousePosition; //получаем экранные координаты
    var worldCursor = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos); //превращаем в мировые
    var aim = new Vector3(worldCursor.x, worldCursor.y, transform.position.z); //устанавливаем z равный z нашего персонажа
    if (worldCursor.magnitude > 0)
    {
        var newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, aim, _distance); //Сдвигаем точку от положения персонажа, в сторону цели не дальше, чем на _distance
        CrossHair.transform.position = newPos; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Ага, я примерно понял, но при использовании данного кода, прицел двигается за игроком, на определенной дистанции (_distance), но не двигается за мышью.

Comment: @Александр, не совсем. Сейчас он двигается от игрока к мыши не больше, чем на _distance. Т.е. если мышь ближе - прицел прямо под ней, если дальше - он на расстоянии _distance. Вы какого хотите поведения? Чтобы он всегда был под мышью? Тогда вы вообще переусложнили всё жутко просто сразу делайте CrossHair.transform.position = new Vector3(worldCursor.x, worldCursor.y, transform.position.z);

Comment: Я в этом к сожалению ничего не понимаю, я пытаюсь добиться результата, что бы спрайт(прицел) двигался за мышью по окружности вокруг персонажа на определенной дистанции, прикрепил картинку к вопросу, что бы понятнее был мой бред.

Comment: @Александр, так может есть смысл для начала изучить основы языка и **хотя бы** основы векторной алгебры и 2д/3д пространства?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Я задал конкретный вопрос и хотел получить ответ, за что спасибо "M.Green"у, подсказал в чем ошибка, если бы я хотел узнать просто мнение или наставление, для этого я задал бы вопрос на ответах майл ру.

Comment: @Александр, хм, посмотрел картинку. Самое просто, что можно сделать без заморочек - умножать aim на 100 перед MoveToward :D тогда он всегда будет ходить по кромке окружности) но, конечно, можно придумать и более качественный вариант.